# How to validate if parent entity does not child entity in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say I have one to many relationship table ( Ex User - Rent )

```
public class User 
{
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Rent> Rents { get; set; }  
}

public class Rent 
{
        public Int64 VideoId { get; set; }
        public Int64 UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User{get; set;}
        public int RentingLength { get; set; }
        public int RentingCost { get; set; }
}
```

I want to delete a `User` record. Before that, I want to check whether `User` has references to `Rent` or not.

What I have is :

```
context.Users.Include("Rents").ToList();
```

then check `Rent` list is null or not.

Is there any better way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any primary key in any of the entity. How is it generating DB?

Comment: actually is not full code. model class in example have base class. In base class I put all common field include field to generate primary key.

Answer (score 1):

`context.Users.Include("Rents").ToList();` will materialize your query, getting all users. Best way should be `context.Rent.Where(r => r.userId == DesiredUserId).Any()`. If `true` then user has rents.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Any` like this to check if record exits

```
public bool Exists(int YourUserId)
{
    dbcontext.Rent.Any(e => e.UserId == YourUserId);
}
```

Comment: You are querying Users so `e` will be user. Your query will get the user with all the rents he has. Meaning your function will always return `true`

Comment: yes you r right.edited the answer.it should be queried on rent

Answer (score 0):

You are using Virtual keyword in navigational properties which means Rents will automatically be included in your query of Users. So you don't need the Include Explicitly.

So you can just do

```
context.Users.Find(Id)
```

And it will include Rent as well for the user with primary key id